# How do I submit wallpapers to be considered for inclusion in Ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-background, artwork, photography

I take photos from time to time, and if I take an exceptionally beautiful one, I'd like to submit it for inclusion in Ubuntu. Where do I send/upload it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add it to the Ubuntu Artwork pool, here: http://www.flickr.com/groups/ubuntu-artwork/

A team of judges will select somewhere around 15 photos from this pool for the default wallpapers.

Comment: Too bad we need to create a Yahoo! account just for these submissions. It would be interesting to have something integrated with Launchpad, or better yet OpenID.