# I'd like to give for free several landscape images I made, to be used as desktop backgrounds in future releases

Tags: desktop-background, community, donation

I want to give for free several very nice images I took, to be included as optional backgrounds. If you know how I can do it, please tell me!

Cheers!

Comment: Interesting question, I found https://askubuntu.com/q/53/480481 and https://askubuntu.com/q/412745/480481, but both seem outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Contact one of the maintainers of Ubuntu's Wallpaper listed at  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-wallpapers